# Parameter index out of range (2 > number of parameters, which is 1)

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

I wrote following java method and when I call it, gives me the error

```
Parameter index out of range (2 > number of parameters, which is 1).
```

Can anyone please explain me what's wrong with my code?

Thanks a lot in advance!

here is the code

```
private void updateTskUserEmail( Connection hrmsCon ) throws SQLException
{
    ResultSet rsUserEmailMap = null;

    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    PreparedStatement psEmail = null;


    for ( String lbUserEmail : lbUserList )
    {

        try
        {
            String query = "SELECT * FROM tsk_user WHERE email=? ";

            int count = 0;
            ps = hrmsCon.prepareStatement( query );

            if ( lbUserEmail == null )
            {
                ps.setNull( ++count, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR );
            }
            else
            {
                ps.setString( ++count, lbUserEmail );
            }

            rsUserEmailMap = ps.executeQuery();
            while ( rsUserEmailMap.next() )
            {
                String queryInsert = "INSERT INTO tsk_user_email (";
                queryInsert += "user_email,";
                queryInsert += "user_id)";
                queryInsert += " VALUES(?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE user_id=? ";

                int countInsert = 0;
                psEmail = hrmsCon.prepareStatement( query );

                if ( lbUserEmail == null )
                {
                    psEmail.setNull( ++countInsert, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR );
                }
                else
                {
                    psEmail.setString( ++countInsert, lbUserEmail );
                }
                psEmail.setInt( ++countInsert, rsUserEmailMap.getInt( "user_id" ) );
                psEmail.setInt( ++countInsert, rsUserEmailMap.getInt( "user_id" ) );

                psEmail.execute();

            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if ( ps != null )
            {
                ps.close();
            }
            if ( rsUserEmailMap != null )
            {
                rsUserEmailMap.close();
            }
            psEmail.close();
        }
    }

}
```

full stack trace

```
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (2 > number of parameters, which is 1).
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1075)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:984)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:929)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.checkBounds(PreparedStatement.java:3711)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setInternal(PreparedStatement.java:3695)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setInternal(PreparedStatement.java:3737)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setInt(PreparedStatement.java:3681)
    at it.codegen.LbEmailMapper.updateTskUserEmail(LbEmailMapper.java:155)
    at it.codegen.LbEmailMapper.main(LbEmailMapper.java:47)
```

Comment: A full stacktrace or the the method name would be helpful.

Comment: Hi KARASZI István, I just added it to the question :)...

Comment: is this duplicate line a mistake? `psEmail.setInt( ++countInsert, rsUserEmailMap.getInt( "user_id" ) );`

Comment: I think I found the mistake I have done :) psEmail = hrmsCon.prepareStatement( query ); should be psEmail = hrmsCon.prepareStatement( queryInsert ); Thanks a lot everyone :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use

```
psEmail = hrmsCon.prepareStatement(queryInsert );
```

instead of

```
psEmail = hrmsCon.prepareStatement( query );
```

You should be careful when copy & paste code... :-)